# Populate select options from API with React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state

I'm trying to create a dropdown with some JSON responses from an API. Here's an example of what I have:

```
class Test extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        numbers: [],
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=500')
        .then(results => {
            return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let result = data.results.map((cellNumbers) => {
                return ( 
                    <div key={cellNumbers.cell}>
                        {cellNumbers.cell}
                    </div>
                )
            })
            this.setState({ numbers: result });
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Fetch error: ", err);
        });
}
render() {
    return ( 
        <div> {this.state.numbers} </div>
    )
    }
}

export default class Tests extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <div className="row" >
                <div className="col-md-12 buttonCustom" >
                    <select>
                        <option value={<Test />}><Test /></option>
                    </select>
                </div> 
            </div>        
        );
    }
}
```

Right now the dropdown does not separate the different cellNumber values from eachother, so it is one large dropdown with all numbers as one option. How can I get it to separate it? I know there is an npm package react-select, but I was wondering if there was a way of doing it without another package?

Comment: Does cellNumbers.cell return just one result for each cellNumber?

Comment: there are a number of issues with your code, but in general you need to render an `option` for each cell using `this.state.cellNumbers.map`